# Import data from database and textfile to a datagridview

Tags: vb.net

i want to import data from txt file and database to a datagridview like this
first and second columns from txtfile third from database fourth from txt file is simple as that
i can import from txtfile and i can import from database myproblem
how to mix them in datagridview
i need just any idea how it work
or how i import a data to just 2 first columns after that i make query to third column after i return to txtfile and complete fill the datagridview from txt file
its like all datagridview from txtfile but in middle i want to add a new columns for database query

```
    Dim ouvrir As New OpenFileDialog
    If ouvrir.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
        Dim sr As New StreamReader(ouvrir.FileName)
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("select * from EntetedemandeI", cn)
        Dim da As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
        While Not sr.EndOfStream
            DataGridView1.Rows.Add(sr.ReadLine.Split(CChar(vbTab)))
        End While
        While da.Read
            DataGridView1.Rows.Add(da("Numero"))
        End While
    End If
```

Comment: I offered advice on how to do this elsewhere and you basically ignored it. The question is even less appropriate here because SO requires you to have a specific problem, which means you need to show what you've already tried. If you haven't tried anything then you don't have a specific problem but, rather, a need to research.

Comment: Long code snippets are virtually unreadable in comments, especially unformatted. Please do some reading to learn how this site works, then edit your question to an acceptable standard. Start with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) at a minimum.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how but my previous comment does not contain what I intended. What I meant to say was that long code snippets are all but unreadable in comments, especially when unformatted. You should follow the three links I provided to learn a bit about how this site works and there's more in the Help Center besides, including information about formatting.

Comment: OK, that's weird. My second comment looked corrupted so I posted my third comment but, as I submitted, I noticed that my second comment looked OK again. Not sure what's up with that.

Comment: Note that I wasn't suggesting that you should format your code snippet in a comment but rather not post it in a comment at all.  Edit your question to include all the relevant information that it should have included to begin with.

Comment: Is there any relationship between the text file and the data from the database?